# Office JS taskpane addin loading issue after deployment in the server withour SRC (Source) folder for Excel

Tags: iis, deployment, directory, office-js, src

I am not able to load excel taskpane addin. I have deployed the files in the IIS server including the metadata file and asset folder. I did not uploaded the SRC(Source folder) folder.

I have checked if I will upload the SRC folder then it is working as expected.

Is it necessary to upload the SRC  folder?

How will I deploy the office JS application without SRC files?

Please give me some details.

Comment: Hi Suntanu, it would be helpful to provide what starting point that you're working from to help us give you better feedback on what to try. Are you using Visual Studio/VS Code/Yo Office? Are you starting from a project template or a sample? If so which one?

Comment: Hi Sean, 

I am using VS code. It is officejs addin application. I have build my application using "npm run build:dev" command. If I will upload the file from dist folder only then the application not loaded and expecting the html and css files. So after the src (source) folder uploaded in the server then it is working as expected.

Thanks, Sutanu